# Graylog Regex Replace Extractor Ungreedy

Tags: java, regex, logging, regex-lookarounds, graylog

I'm trying to create a Regex Replace Graylog Extractor that can allow me to get an ID passed as path parameters.

The two cases I need to manage are the followings:

```
/v1/api2/5eb98050122d484001708a11
```

```
/v1/api1/5eb98050122d484001708a11/61b3330151e541232146bfb7/
```

The ID is always a 24 alphanumerical string.

First case is easy:

```
^.*([A-Za-z0-9]{24}).*$
```

First group matches the regex (https://regex101.com/r/Idu5Mp/1).

I need to always match the first ID: `5eb98050122d484001708a11`

Also, I need it to match with the first group since in the configuration of the extractor I would use the replacement with `$1`.

Only solution I could find is to make the Regex `Ungreedy`, this way the first ID encountered will resolve the regex. Sadly I don't think it's possible to add Regex Flags in Graylog Regex Patterns.

Is there an alternative way to make the regex ungreedy?

Edit:
I've also tried the following one without any success. I don't understand why it always gets the second id within the first group.

`^.*\/([A-Za-z0-9]{24})(?:\/[A-Za-z0-9]{24})?.*$`

[image: Regex shown]

Comment: `5eb98050122d484001708a11f` is 25 chars long. Try `.*\/([A-Za-z0-9]{24})(?:\/.*)?$` / `.*/([A-Za-z0-9]{24})(?:/.*)?$`

Comment: I've tried it but it seems it's not working: https://regex101.com/r/K6lC1r/1
regex101.com said there were errors with the char `/`

I've also tried on the Graylog interface where it is possible to test.

Comment: No ideas how you failed to copy and paste the pattern. There **two** patterns separated with `/` in the top comment. The real test is at https://regex101.com/r/K6lC1r/2 Also, you need to show how you are using the regex in the target environment.

Comment: But I don't need two patterns. I need one that matches in both cases and encloses into group 1 the onlye id in the first string and the first id in the second string.

I'm running the test in the graylog interface for Extractor creation.

Comment: The two patterns are the same (just `/` is unescaped in the second version). So it is basically one pattern. The first string you provided contains a 25-char substring, not 24. So your requirements are not clear: is that 24- OR 25-char string you are looking for?

Comment: Sorry, I've corrected. Both are 24

Comment: So, if it is really Java regex flavor, the `.*/([A-Za-z0-9]{24})(?:/.*)?$` regex will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
.*/([A-Za-z0-9]{24,})(?:/.*)?$
```

Replace with `$1`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/K6lC1r/4).

*Details*:

- `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `/` - a `/` char
- `([A-Za-z0-9]{24,})` - Group 1: 24 or more alphanumeric ASCII chars
- `(?:/.*)?` - an optional sequence of `/` and any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: It should always match `5eb98050122d484001708a11`, but it doesn't

Comment: @Xfox You are changing the requirements on the fly. The solution is the same, just ADJUST the quantifier - here you have 23 chars. Just use `.*/([A-Za-z0-9]{20,})(?:/.*)?$` - https://regex101.com/r/K6lC1r/6